# MySQL JOIN on three tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

**addresses**

```
id, address, city, zipcode
```

**persons** (1500 records)

```
id, address_id, firtname, lastname, sex, title
```

**buildings** (100 records)

```
id, address_id, name, type_of_building
```

Multiple persons/buildings share the same address. I need to list all addresses with its person or building info. So, my query should return a total of 1600 records.

What kind of query do I need to write to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need all of the records from two different datasets, you need to use an `INNER JOIN` with a [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html). Something like this might work:

```
SELECT p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, p.sex, p.title, a.address, a.city, a.zipcode
FROM persons p
  INNER JOIN addresses a on a.id = p.address_id

UNION ALL

SELECT b.id, b.name, '', '', b.type_of_building, a.address, a.city, a.zipcode
FROM buildings b
  INNER JOIN addresses a on a.id = b.address_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a **UNION**, because you want to merge the results of two different datasets. In order to get the unified information, you need to use the same fields, so I will use samples:

```
(SELECT address_id, firstname AS value1, lastname AS value2, sex AS value3, title AS value4 FROM persons)
    UNION
(SELECT address_id, name AS value1, type_of_building AS value2, 0 AS value3, 0 AS value4 FROM buildings)
```